# display the time from strtotime without showind am or pm

Tags: php, html, datetime

Hi, In my php web site, I need to display the time in 24 hours system. I.e. not in am/pm.  I have a date `03/17/2012 9:40 PM` I want to display this as

```
17-03-2012 21:40
```

Is there is any function to achieve this in php?
I have searched a lot, but fail.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out `strftime()`:

```
echo strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("m/d/Y H:i", strtotime("03/17/2012 9:40 PM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "03/17/2012 9:40 PM";
$time = strtotime($date);
$new_date = date('d-m-Y H:i', $time);
echo $new_date; // results in 17-03-2012 21:40
```

This will probably work, no?

Comment: Same approach as @Julien, only more lines :p